# Cannot assign value of type 'MRData' to type '[F1Data]' when trying to parse JSON

Tags: json, swift4, codable, decoder

I have been wrestling with this for a while. I am trying to parse a JSON Api into a UITableview. The url is [Formula One API](https://ergast.com/api/f1/1999/driverstandings.json)  . I am using Codable rather than third party pods.  Thought this might cut down on the amount of code.  Although, as the API is not that straight forward it is hard to extract what I want.  Basically, I want to list the current standing for drivers for a given year. In url and code I have given I have chosen 1999 as an example.  I have been researching on Stackoverflow but each solution is very specific to a particular problem and I can't seem to relate to my issue.  Below is the code I have.

```
struct MRData: Codable {
let xmlns: String?
let series: String?
let url: String?
let limit, offset, total: String?
let standingsTable: StandingsTable

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case xmlns, series, url, limit, offset, total
    case standingsTable = "StandingsTable"
 }
}

struct StandingsTable: Codable {
let season: String?
let standingsLists: [StandingsList]

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case season
    case standingsLists = "StandingsLists"
 }
}

struct StandingsList: Codable {
let season, round: String?
let driverStandings: [DriverStanding]

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case season, round
    case driverStandings = "DriverStandings"
  }
 }

struct DriverStanding: Codable {
let position, positionText, points, wins: String?
let driver: Driver
let constructors: [Constructor]

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case position, positionText, points, wins
    case driver = "Driver"
    case constructors = "Constructors"
 }
 }

struct Constructor: Codable {
let constructorId: String?
let url: String?
let name: String?
let nationality: String?
}

struct Driver: Codable {
let driverId: String?
let url: String?
let givenName, familyName, dateOfBirth, nationality: String?
}

class f1TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var champions: [F1Data] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //        let jsonUrlString = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/jsondecodable/website_description"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationItem.title = "Champion Drivers"
    fetchJSON()
}
private func fetchJSON(){
    let jsonUrlString = "https://ergast.com/api/f1/1999/driverstandings.json"

    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to get data from url:", err)
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                // Swift 4.1
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                self.champions = try decoder.decode(MRData.self, from: data)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                //let season = f1Data.mrData.standingsTable.season

                //                let firstDriver = f1Data.mrData.standingsTable.standingsLists[0].driverStandings
                //                for driver in firstDriver {
                //
                //                    print("\(driver.driver.givenName) \(driver.driver.familyName)")
                //                }
                //print(season)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        }.resume()
}
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
// MARK: - Table view data source

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return champions.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cellId")

    let champion = champions[indexPath.row]
    let driverName = champion.mrData.standingsTable.standingsLists[0].driverStandings
    for driver in driverName {
        cell.textLabel?.text = driver.driver.familyName
    }
    //cell.textLabel?.text =
    //cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(course.numberOfLessons)
    return cell
   }

}
```

Now I realize that the error is in the do catch block.

```
do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                // Swift 4.1
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                self.champions = try decoder.decode(MRData.self, from: data)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
```

and that the array F1Data cannot be a dictionary of MRData. So if I change it to the following `self.champions = try decoder.decode([F1Data].self, from: data)` the I get another error which is 
`debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))`.  Any help would be appreciated with this.

Comment: Please **read** your code. The error is pretty clear. You decode `MRData` and `champions` is declared as `[F1Data]`. There is no struct `F1Data` at all in the JSON hierarchy.

Comment: I have added the following as my champions variable `var champions: [DriverStanding] = []` and the following as the decoder `do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    // Swift 4.1
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                    self.champions = try decoder.decode([DriverStanding].self, from: data)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()` The error I am getting is the following `debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))`  Any help please.

Comment: You have to decode always the complete structure starting with the root object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I know if I do that I get another error . I will try this later and post the error.

Answer (score 0):

As Vadian correctly said that you need to decode at the root of your object.  I briefly watched this [video](https://youtu.be/d9LtFtia4vc) and the penny dropped! Assign the decoder to a variable and add to decode the complete structure starting at the root object.

```
guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                // Swift 4.1
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                let firstDriver = try decoder.decode(F1Data.self, from: data)
                self.champions = firstDriver.mrData.standingsTable.standingsLists[0].driverStandings
                self.tableView.reloadData()
```